# How to allow public pull requests on bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I'm trying to set up a public repository on Bitbucket for video game localization files and allow anyone (including anonymous/unrelated users) to branch and submit pull requests. It seems that branching is working fine, but I can't find a way to allow users to submit pull requests.
[image]

I have set merge via pull request available to "everybody" at the project level, but my buddy testing for me still can't click the "Create pull request" button as it says he does not have permission.

Is there a way to get this to work on Bitbucket? Or failing that, is there a way to get this to work somewhere else?